# Why assert for null on a object before asserting on some of its internals?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, null, assertions, xunit

Let's consider the following test.

```
[Fact]
public void MyTest()
{
     // Arrange Code
     var sut = new SystemWeTest();

     // Act Code
     var response = sut.Request();

     // Assert
     response.Should().NotBeNull();
     response.ResponseCode.Should().Be("1");
     response.Errors.Should().BeEmpty();
}
```

I have argued with a few colleagues that it's pointless to assert that 'response' is not null **if** you are going to then assert on some of its internals. Of course, if the only thing that you are interested is checking that the object is not null, nothing more, then it's fine.

My thinking is that each following assert statements are in fact implicit assertions that 'response' is not null. If it is null then it would throw a null reference exception and making the test fail as expected.

The only benefit I see from doing this is a somewhat clearer message on why the test failed. You'd get your test framework specific exception that's thrown by the 'NotBeBull' assertion instead of the generic 'nullReferenceException'. I don't feel this is useful as you are getting the same information anyway.

Am I missing something here? Does checking for null have any benefits in the example provided?

Comment: "I have argued with a few colleagues that it's pointless to assert that 'response' is not null if you are going to then assert on some of it's internals." - While a clear error message is important, saves time, and while an explicit assert clearly communicates the specification, ultimately, spending time on debating this is [bike-shedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality).

Comment: The test verifies the contract is met. If non-nullability is part of the contract then *that specifically should be tested*.

Comment: You can write a custom response code matcher which checks all three: the response is not null, the error is empty, and the response code matches. Then everybody's happy and response tests are consistent.

Comment: For future maintainers of this code _who do not know what you know now_ it is important to know how to fix the test if a return value suddenly is null.  Explicitly asserting means that the test handles this case correctly.  Not asserting means that the test might be incomplete.

Comment: If the Request method was marked explicitly as not being able to return null, then this would not be an issue in the first place.  Put as much information in your code as you can - it helps the compiler helping you.

Comment: If you didn't check that `response` wasn't null, the next check a property of `response` would throw a null ref exception - far from helpful. Also, these tests could be vastly improved by adding the "because" argument to each call to "Be".

Comment: Everyone else has listed the many upsides to having the null check, but what about the downsides? Well... there's an extra line of code. I think that's it.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović sometimes it's worth debating small examples in order to set standards and develop broad agreement in the future, which might avert _future_ debates.

Comment: Out of curiosity is `Should().NotBeNull()` the same as _MUST_ not be null?

Comment: @shadowtalker - sure, but it's not so much about agreement, as it is about investigating what's *actually* important. I realize this might be an incomplete/toy example, but here, there are far more important discussion topics. *That* was my point. Like, can this test give false positives? What's the contract (or behavior) that this test is supposed to be specifying? What are the assumptions/preconditions? How to actually write an isolated test in a way that communicates all of that right there in code? How to write a test that's not fragile? In that light, the null check is barely relevant.

Comment: @TommyAndersen: unit tests are specifications. You describe what *should* happen. You really hope that it will happen, but you cannot be sure, and that's why you write tests. If it doesn't happen, you want to get an error message as soon as possible.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović . I can see how this would be seen as bike-shedding. But in order to affirm that you'd need to know my team context. In our case we have already taken care of the 'bigger issues' so i don't think it's fair to refer to this question as bike-shedding. You are going to need that bike shed at one point ;)

Comment: Writing “assert (p != NULL)” takes ten seconds if you are slow. Why discuss it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m going to agree with everyone else, but with a slightly different focus: unit tests are a way to assert your understanding of how the code under test is supposed to behave and what some data is supposed to look like afterwards *and convey that same understanding to someone that just reads the test*.

In a language like JavaScript, you might assert that the result of a function call is an int or a string, in another language the compiler might take care of that for you by refusing to compile.

You are dealing with C#, if you don’t have nullable enabled **AND** it is your understanding that a particular value should not be null, then you should **ABSOLUTELY** have a test that verifies that that value is not null.  Regardless of it coincidentally being tested by some other test.  Now, whether that test should be included in a larger test or separately in its own isolated test, is a more difficult question.  The more complex a test is, the harder it is to understand, but testing for null doesn’t make it that much more complex.

And then of course there is the question of what to do when nullable **is** enabled.  Your understanding is that the value shouldn’t be null and the compiler only semi-enforces that. What to do?

Asserting that it’s not supposed to be null in that case doesn’t add to the hypothetical readers understanding, the language itself conveys that information. Include a specific test for null only if it’s been an actual problem and you are testing for regression *and include that fact in the comments*.

Comment: I came to realise that this question probably does not have a definite answer as the context ( the team, the language, the expectations,..) can vary a lot. For now I will select this answer.
Those are some of the reasons for my choice : 
It takes into account the context of different language ( weak typing vs strong typing )  and the implications it brings.It also raises the fact that C# can enable nullable and this changes the expectations of the users ( and the fact that it's semi-enforced by compiler )

Answer (score 75):

> Does checking for null has any benefits in the example provided ?

> The only benefit I see from doing this is a somewhat clearer message on why the test failed.

You have successfully answered your own question. Clear error messages on test failures are *very* useful.

Comment: I agree that it's important but you are getting the same information either way, that's why I stated that for me it's barely a benefit over not explicitely asserting. So is there any other benefits or would that be all ?

Comment: @BAmadeusJ, how would you tell if the nullPointerReference was coming from an assert in your test, or a bug in your SUT?

Comment: The stacktrace would tell me which line caused the issue and from there it's trivial to understand what hapenned.

Comment: @BAmadeusJ Which would require you to log, see, and interpret the stacktrace. Which *may* be anything but trivial. "You are getting the same information either way", as you stated, but **how** that information is presented can be just as important. Information is only information when you can parse (grok, grep, ...) it, otherwise it's just meaningless data.

Comment: @Duroth In my case it's unit tests run locally where all relevant informations are visible in the test runner but I failed to mention that in the question. I get it, your point is that in an unstructured log environement it's important to be as precise as possible.

Comment: @BAmadeusJ Also consider that while the information may be clear to _you_, some coworkers, especially more junior ones, might come across a nullPointerReference and assume that the test is corrupt. An explicit assertion removes any possible ambiguity. It does not require you to further interpret the given information. In short: It's more idiot-proof, which may or may not be important, depending on your opinion of your coworkers. :)

Comment: This could be a good answer if some of the arguments and examples from the comments were included.

Comment: @duroth If the stack trace doesn't clearly show the line with the error, you need a best test environment.  Especially given that this test has multiple asserts.  (Which, IMO, is perfectly fine, since I assume you have a clear stack trace and competent programmers)

Comment: @Duroth TBH the OP sounds like the more junior member of the team, more experienced devs generally recognise the value of giving their future selves all the help they possibly can - such knowledge gained through painful experience!  :-)

Answer (score 22):

### Code should be unambiguous where possible

If a random NullPointer is thrown in a test, I'm starting to investigate if the program is at fault, or if the writer of the test did just miss the fact of a variable possible being null. If someone writes "shouldNotBeNull" the intent is clear. This variable can and should never be null.

This of course assumes people don't just copy & paste a pattern blindly, but use the check where it makes sense and an if-null otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

I have written a lot of unit tests.

I want *basic* facts to be tested first.  I wrote those tests first, and I ensured my code passed them first.

When I write more advanced tests, my goal is to test those more advanced situations.  They may also test the basic facts, but *that is at best a side effect*.

I may refactor them later.  Maybe the rules have changed, and now the proper way to get a response is `processor.responseCode(response)`.  And the `responseCode` method on `processor` handles null.

So my unit test now reads

```
processor.responseCode(response).Should().Be("1");
```

My refactoring of the test removed the "the response isn't null" requirement.  It tests for the responseCode is `"1"`.

If I *actually cared* that `response` cannot be null, then this perfectly correct refactoring made me lose that test.  If I didn't care if `response` is null or not, then the previous test was an error and shouldn't have been checked!

However, that later change has a risk; my production code may have relied upon `response` never being null and behave badly.  My decision to eliminate that test from the unit test thus requires me to audit the use of the `response` object.

A second reason to have the null check explicit is that complex tests can lead to complex errors.  Having to parse the failure message of a line testing for a value of `"1"` to be because one specific parameter is null is extra work.

With it being on its own line, the line tests one thing, and clearly explains what went wrong.  In some frameworks I'll even early exit to not spam the output with a bunch of additional errors from the fact the value was null and later tests are expected to fail.

A faster, easier to understand unit test failure makes iteration faster.  When I rewrite the `.Request()` and it hits the null error, I can see my mistake instantly, and make it non-null. Then I realize I missed some parameters, and fix those, and repeat.

In this ideal world, the unit test *writes my code* for me, or at least tells me what feature to add next.  The smaller the piece of code the faster the iteration is and the less likely I (or the jr developer working on it) will get lost.

Answer (score 6):

> I have argued with a few colleagues that it's pointless to assert that 'response' is not null if you are going to then assert on some of it's internals.

It might be "technically" pointless to do so, but code is much more than being about "technically" right.

Code conveys intend and asserting that `response` is not null says `sut.Request()` should not return `NULL`.

In addition to that, it adds a faster fail path, which is always¹ good.

¹ most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents:

Besides clear error message I would say I see benefits if internally your code logs if your response is null, but It should have a implicit test for that.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you're writing a test and you know a nullable object shouldn't be null, you can just add the check without trying to think if an implicit check already exists. You also won't end up losing test coverage if all of the implicit checks get removed for whatever reason (e.g. changing requirements, different test structure, copy-pasting).

Answer (score 1):

**Automated Test Parsing Tools can use the difference to distinguish between Sut.Request() returning an empty non-null value unexpectedly vs Sut.Request() getting a null response value**

When evaluating the following line, there's a problem when determining what is Null:

> response.ResponseCode.Should().Be("1");

Namely, both "response" *and* "ResponseCode" could be null - and you'll need to look into the stack trace to try and find out, specifically, which one is null.

Granted, that probably shouldn't happen - any response that is given, if (For example) HTTPResponse, should have a responseCode, so it *should* only come up with a null response object itself.

But if there's something wrong with the sut.Request() call - either in the code itself, or the specific way it requests a resource - that could likely indicate an environment issue (i.e. network service not started, something else weird going on.).

Checking for Null on the response itself beforehand reduces the issues to one on that line for NullPointerExceptions - you can indicate that something's wrong with the Environment that it interacts with, or the area it's trying to reach, if the response it's working with is Null, relative to "The responseCode is null". That's indicating the response itself exists, but the responseCode does not.

If you've encountered these type of issues intermittently before, you can write your test structure or reporting system to automatically classify these as two different errors, indicative of different approaches to fix them.

This can be useful if your testing code runs as a monitoring aspect of a larger thing - as far as diagnostics, you can take those two different stack traces, and definitively indicate what has historically been an issue with that.